# Bootstrap Icons not displayed in Gulp 4

Tags: javascript, css, sass, gulp, font-awesome

I'm trying to use the new bootstrap icons npm package with gulp 4 the latest version in my project everything is installed well and worked well.

the issue that I got is when I declare the icon in my **index.html** file like this :

```
<i class="bi bi-alarm"></i>
```

the icon does not show up I think the problem is coming from the web fonts.

I'm new with gulp if anyone can help, please!

**here is my gulpfile.js file:**

```
"use strict";

const { src, dest, watch, series, parallel } = require("gulp");
const sass = require("gulp-sass");
const postcss = require("gulp-postcss");
const autoprefixer = require("autoprefixer");
const cssnano = require("cssnano");
const terser = require("gulp-terser");
const browsersync = require("browser-sync").create();

// FILE PATHS
const files = {
    scssPath: "src/assets/scss/app.scss",
    jsPath: "src/assets/js/app.js",
};

// COMPILE SCSS INTO CSS
function compileSCSS() {
    return src(files.scssPath, { sourcemaps: true })
        .pipe(sass().on("error", sass.logError))
        .pipe(postcss([autoprefixer(), cssnano()]))
        .pipe(dest("public/assets/css", { sourcemaps: "." }));
}

// COPY CUSTOM JS
function compileJS() {
    return src(files.jsPath, { sourcemaps: true })
        .pipe(terser())
        .pipe(dest("public/assets/js", { sourcemaps: "." }));
}

// BROWSER SYNC
function browserSyncInit(cb) {
    browsersync.init({
        server: {
            baseDir: ".",
        },
    });
    cb();
}

function browsersyncReload(cb) {
    browsersync.reload();
    cb();
}

// WATCH FILES
function watchFiles() {
    watch("*.html", browsersyncReload);
    watch([files.scssPath, files.jsPath], series(compileSCSS, compileJS, browsersyncReload));
}

exports.default = series(parallel(compileSCSS, compileJS), browserSyncInit, watchFiles);
```

**here is my src/assets/scss/app.scss file:**

```
@import "../../../node_modules/bootstrap-icons/font/bootstrap-icons";
```

**here is my file structure:**

```
my-project/
├── src/assets/scss
│   └── app.scss
├── src/assets/js
│   └── app.js
├── public/assets
│   └── css/
│   └── js/
└── node_modules/
└── index.html
└── gulpfile.js
```

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap Icons use [Webfont](https://github.com/twbs/icons/blob/main/font/bootstrap-icons.css#L3), but you just imported SCSS only, so it is not working correctly. Let create a Gulp task to copy [fonts](https://github.com/twbs/icons/tree/main/font/fonts) to your `dest` too.

Gulp task suggestion:

```
function copyBootstrapFonts() {
  return gulp.src('path-to-bootstrap-icons/fonts')
    .pipe(gulp.dest('path-to-your-dest/fonts'));
}
```

Or you can use [CDN](http://@import%20url(%22https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.4.1/font/bootstrap-icons.css%22);) as an easy way.

Comment: can you show me how to create this task please

Comment: @jhon-jhones I just added Gulp task suggestion, not tested but it should work. Let me know if you need more.

Comment: it copies the font of the directory but it still the icons not diplayed ??

Comment: Seem you need to put the `fonts` folder to the same as the CSS file as dest. Because they import as `./fonts/bootstrap-icons.woff2`

Comment: Your fonts dest should be `public/assets/css/fonts/`, don't forget to Inspect to check the error in Console if any too.